# Java Atmosphere Jersey return JSON Object from Broadcastable

Tags: java, json, websocket, jersey, atmosphere

I am trying to return a JSON representation of a JAXB annotated POJO using Atmosphere.

```
@Path("/entity/{topic}")
public class JerseyPubSub
{
    @PathParam("topic")
    private Broadcaster topic;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public SuspendResponse<String> subscribe()
    {
        return new SuspendResponse.SuspendResponseBuilder<String>()
            .broadcaster(topic)
            .outputComments(true)
            .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Broadcast
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Broadcastable publish(Notification notification)
    {
        return new Broadcastable(notification, topic);
    }
}
```

I know that my data binding is working as POSTing the JSON 'Notification' Object works.

Is there anyway I can convert the Object passed into 'new Broadcastable()' to a JSON Object, using the JAXB JSON serialization?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
@AtmosphereService(broadcaster=JerseyBroadcaster.class)
@Path("entity/{topic}")
public class WebService {
@PathParam(value="topic")
String topic;
@Context
private BroadcasterFactory factory;


    @Suspend(contentType = "application/json", listeners = {OnDisconnect.class})
    @GET
    public Broadcastable suspend() {
        return new Broadcastable( factory.lookup(topic, true ) );       
    }


    @Broadcast(writeEntity = false)
    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response publish(Notification notification) {
        return new Response(notification);
    }


    public static final class OnDisconnect extends AtmosphereResourceEventListenerAdapter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebService.class);


    @Override
        public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
            if (event.isCancelled()) {
               logger.info("Browser {} unexpectedly disconnected", event.getResource().uuid());
            } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {
               logger.info("Browser {} closed the connection", event.getResource().uuid());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help... :)